# Importing modules from sibling folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I want to import `utils_file.py` into `scripts_file.py`. I already tried to add an empty `__init__.py` but it didn't work. I saw many times the solution with `sys` but I'm not a big fan of it. Are there other solutions? Here the structure:

`applications/scripts/scripts_file.py` and
`applications/utils_utils_file.py`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you run your program. For simplicity, make sure your terminal directory is inside application. Here is a way to do it:

scripts_file.py:

```
import utils_file.py

#Run your functions here e.g
potato(100)
```

utils_file.py:

```
#Potato functions
def potato(num):

    print(num)
```

Just make sure when you run your program, you run scripts_file.py.